# Deploy windows "send to" extension

Tags: windows, batch, vbscript

I developed a small VB script to be included in windows "send to" section in the context menu.

I know how to implement the script to be used this way by linking or copying the file into:

```
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

Now I have to deploy the script to about 1200 clients with some being used by more than one user.

The deployment is done by the ivanti/landesk management console if this matters.

Currently I only can think of one way to guarantee every user will be able to use it by deploying a batch script into the public startup folder located at:

```
\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

The batch file then runs at login of each user and copy's the actual script to the users `\SendTo` folder.

I know i could copy the script to the `SendTo` folder of the default user profile. But this would mean only new user would receive it.

Is this the intended way to do this work or is there any more convenient practice?

Another way i can think of would be to loop through all available user profiles in either the registry and link the file or the users directory and copy the files to the corresponding %APPDATA%'s. This looks like more effort than I should need for such a task.